# How to get data from database column and display in dropdownlist using asp.net + vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I try to get year from a column `UPDATE_DATE` in a SQL Server database. And I want to display it in a dropdownlist. But, I get this error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'UPDATE_DATE'

Here is my source code: If i remove YEAR from that, it will not show  the error. how actually the correct way to do this using YEAR

```
strsql = "SELECT DISTINCT year(UPDATE_DATE) FROM [FixedAssetMaster_old]  "

da = New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, Conn)
Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
da.Fill(ds2)
da.Dispose()

ddlFinYear.DataSource = ds2
ddlFinYear.DataTextField = "UPDATE_DATE"
ddlFinYear.DataValueField = "UPDATE_DATE"
ddlFinYear.DataBind()

ddlDept.Items.Insert(0, "")
ds2.Dispose()
```

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I would add an order by clause in the Select statement, so the years would be in some sensible order for the user to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strsql = "SELECT DISTINCT year(UPDATE_DATE) as ABC FROM [FixedAssetMaster_old]  "

da = New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, Conn)
Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
da.Fill(ds2)
da.Dispose()

ddlFinYear.DataSource = ds2
ddlFinYear.DataTextField = "ABC"
ddlFinYear.DataValueField = "ABC"
ddlFinYear.DataBind()

ddlDept.Items.Insert(0, "")
ds2.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 2):

A `DataSet` can have many tables in it. This code only creates one, but there was no way for the `DataSource` property on a DropdownList to know that. Use `ds2.Tables(0)` for the data source so it will know which table to look at.

Comment: Or use a `DataTable` instead of a `DataSet` from the beginning, if only one `DataTable` is being fetched anyway .....